# Where are the api docs/implementation of Jenkinsfile pipeline methods?

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

e.g. I found some narrative docs like:
https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/running-multiple-steps/#timeouts-retries-and-more

They show there are two methods `timeout` and `retry`, but the arguments they take are not detailed except via some example code. (it's very frustrating that keywords highlighted in the docs, like `retry`, aren't linked to some definitional docs somewhere).

There is this https://javadoc.jenkins.io/ but AFAICT there is no search and I did not manage to find the relevant part in there yet. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Furthermore I would like to look at the implementation, to understand what condition `retry` actually retries under (when exceptions are raised? when some failure value is returned?). I have tried code search on GitHub https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins but could not find the relevant code.

I'm using a Jenkinsfile declarative pipeline with some custom methods defined via a shared library, trying to understand how it will interact with some of these Jenkins builtins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentation about `retry` and `timeout` mentioned in [pipeline's options](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#available-options) and [stage's options](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#stage-options).

[retry](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-basic-steps-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/steps/RetryStep.java) and [timeout](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-basic-steps-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/steps/TimeoutStep.java) are workflow steps and they are parts of `workflow-basic-steps-plugin`.

Execution flow source code you can find [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-basic-steps-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/steps/RetryStepExecution.java) and [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-basic-steps-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/steps/TimeoutStepExecution.java)

Comment: Thanks, I eventually found the code on GitHub last night, same as you have linked to.  I also found this alternative link for `retry` and `timeout` docs which is a bit more explicit about their arguments: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/ (although it wasn't very clear to me at first glance if these docs were applicable to declarative pipeline but it's the same `workflow-basic-steps` plugin)